# why do i get a debug assert failed block_type_is_valid when I delete this char *

Tags: c++, memory

```
 int main(void) {
    const char* kung = "Foo";

    delete []kung;
}
```

In this piece of code, why do I get the following `debug assert failed block_type_is_valid` ?

Is it because kung pointer is pointing to a constant string in the memory which cannot be de-allocated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can't `delete` a string literal (which is what `kung` points to).

You also can't delete an automatic-storage string (so it's not really the literal part):

```
char kung[] = "Foo";
delete []kung;   //still illegal
```

**Only `delete[]` memory you allocate with `new[]`.**

Comment: Ah yes! The same way this is a problem: `int i = 4;
 int *p = &i;

 delete p;`

Comment: @brainydexter yes, but in your example it's even more than that. When you write `const char* kung = "Foo";`, the string resides in a read-only segment of memory. It's illegal to even modify it, not only the delete.

Comment: So, if I had a string like this: char* str = "Kung"; *str++; Would this be a problem ?

Comment: @Luchian, I agree with your statement, but just to point out a detail, as written, brainydexter's code uses *str++, which due to precedence rules, says, 'advance the pointer, then dereference what is found at the new address'. To invoke the bad behavior, he would need to do '(*str)++'.

Comment: @DonWakefield you're right, I knew that didn't look right. :)

Comment: @DonWakefield okay, the one thing I dont understand is, why is it that this does not work with integers in the same way. check out this code: http://ideone.com/BbZJs

Comment: @brainydexter that's how the language is designed. String literals are located in read-only memory. `char* x = "foo"` is in read only memory, `char[] x = "foo"` isn't and you can modify it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Out of curiosity, is this read only memory, also known as the string pool ?

Comment: @brainydexter no. String pool is in java. In C++ there can exist multiple identical strings in different places, so it's not a pool.

Comment: Ah yes, working in multiple languages always makes me mix up things. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @brainydexter, Luchian is correct. Some comments on your example code: 'int i' is 'on the stack', meaning local memory for main. The expression 'cout << (\*p)++' does a couple of things. One, it dereferences the pointer, getting the value 4 for the stream expression, which is what you see in your terminal. Since you use the post-fix increment, the increment of the *temporary* integer containing '4' happens *after* you stream out the '4', and so is discarded silently.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. The postfix operator does in fact increment the original variable i. It just does it after the stream out.